# How to setup database for friends/followers for a social community site using php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

everyone, can someone please help me out on this: I am working on a social networking site as a class project, but I can't seem to find a way to setup friends and/or follower/following database. Please help. Thanks everyone. I am working with PHP/MYSQL.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create something like this of course you can add/rename columns.

**user_table**

- user_id

**friends_table** (Combination user_id_1/user_id_2 unique key)

- user_id_1 //Friend
- user_id_2 //Friend

**follower_table** (Combination user_id_1/user_id_2 unique key)

- user_id_1 //Follower
- user_id_2 //Following

Comment: Thank you very much for that. I think I've got a clue now.